# dplyr::separate and text wrangling

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a text wrangling problem.

I have an excel file that consists mostly of quotes and codes from qualitative interviews. I have little control over how these data look coming out of the qualitative analysis software.

The data tend to look something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(
  id = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007), 
  quote = c("apples are tasty and round", 
            "oranges are round", 
            "grapes are grapes", 
            "broccoli is green",
            "burssel sprouts are green", 
            "eggplant, meh",
            "random thought among other  thoughts"),
  codes = c("fruit::apple::round::tasty",
            "fruit::apple::round", 
            "fruit::grape",
            "vegetable::broccoli::green",
            "vegetable::brussel sprouts::green", 
            "vegetable::eggplant",
            "NA")
)
```

What needs to happen is to splice the codes column into multiple vectors based on the presence of the "::" indicator in each cell of the codes column. Let's take a look at the target dataset that I am trying to create:

```
data_target <- tibble(
  id = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007), 
  quote = c("apples are tasty and round", 
            "oranges are round", 
            "grapes are grapes", 
            "broccoli is green",
            "burssel sprouts are green", 
            "eggplant, meh",
            "random thought among other  thoughts"),
  code_1 = c(rep("fruit", 3), rep("vegetable", 3), "NA"),
  code_2 = c("apple", "apple", "grape", "broccoli", "brussel sprouts", "eggplant", "NA"), 
  code_3 = c("round", "round", "NA", "green", "green", "NA", "NA"), 
  code_4 = c(rep("NA", 7))
)
```

I'm unsure of the best way to tackle this issue. My first thought was to utilize the `dplyr::separate` function; however, the `into` argument for this function requires you to specify the column names you are separating the data into. The issue is the total number of columns can vary for a number of reasons that are irrelevant to the question.

I'm looking for how to best tackle this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the stringr package's `str_split` (or base R's `strsplit`), then unnest, which will return long format. Group by `id` and add another temporary variable for `code_x`, then spread:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

dat %>% 
    mutate(codes = str_split(codes, "::")) %>%
    unnest() %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(vars = paste0("code_", 1:n())) %>% 
    spread(vars, codes)
```

Which returns this dataframe:

```r
     id quote                                code_1    code_2          code_3 code_4
  <dbl> <chr>                                <chr>     <chr>           <chr>  <chr> 
1  1001 apples are tasty and round           fruit     apple           round  tasty 
2  1002 oranges are round                    fruit     apple           round  NA    
3  1003 grapes are grapes                    fruit     grape           NA     NA    
4  1004 broccoli is green                    vegetable broccoli        green  NA    
5  1005 burssel sprouts are green            vegetable brussel sprouts green  NA    
6  1006 eggplant, meh                        vegetable eggplant        NA     NA    
7  1007 random thought among other  thoughts NA        NA              NA     NA
```